# Static Being Heard On the Headsets

Tags: audio, manjaro

I am running Manjaro, kernel 5.17.1-3, on a desktop I built with an Asus Z170-A motherboard, it has 32GB of DDR4-2666 RAM and an Intel Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU.

While using either Firefox or Chromium browser or watching a video in VLC Player the audio is good, however, if I start up one or more VM's in VirtualBox the audio starts to get choppy and I hear a lot of static. The RAM usage does not even reach near the total capacity, it usually hovers around 50% of the total.  Once I shut down the VM the poor audio improves totally.

I use either earbuds with the 3.5mm audio port or a USB headset and get the same issue.

Can anyone advise me on how to solve this? I am new to Linux and so am at a loss.

Regards,
Rakesh.